# Counting similar values on same row, different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write a query that will count how many times a certain value appears on each row - on the full table I have more columns and I need to count how many times "9" (for example) appears in all the columns,

In this case the answer would be 3:

```
PlayerName  Nation  Kills   Deaths  SoloKills   PartyKills
666           1      9        0        9            9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select  PlayerName
,       sum(case when Nation = 9 then 1 else 0 end +
            case when Kills = 9 then 1 else 0 end +
            case when Deaths = 9 then 1 else 0 end +
            ...
        ) as SumOfNines
from    YourTable
group by
        PlayerName
```

Comment: is this for MSSQL aswell? i just tried it and getting error, also this will count how much times 9 appears in the columns right? thanks agian.

Comment: Column 'PK_TODAY_RANK.PlayerName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Right, I forgot the `group by` clause.  Added in the answer now.